# Random 'pageYOffset' is undefined in IE 8 using Dojo 1.9

Tags: javascript, dojo

I seem to have this intermittent issue with a website that I am developing.  Randomly I get:

Error:  'pageYOffset' is undefined

The error appears to be comming from dojox/mobile/common.js.  This is a responsive website that uses Dojo Mobile, but no mobile elements should be active when in IE 8.

I know this is not a supported method my IE 8, but this issue is being generated from Dojo.

Thanks,

Comment: And did you look that property up on say MDN or dottero? Obviously you didn't as then you'd know it's not supported in IE8. Why Dojo mobile messes up, I have no idea, I guess it sucks ?

Comment: I am smarter than the average bear.  Yes, I know it is not supported in IE 8.  However, using a library like Dojo or jQuery this should be abstracted away for me.  I am not the one calling the non-existant property.  It is being called by Dojo.  I am just looking for any assistance to help resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you happen to use an emulated Internet Explorer 8 (meaning, Internet Explorer 9, 10 or 11 in some sort of a compatibility mode)?

Comment: I have tested in IE 8 straight up and that is where I see the issue.  All other versions of IE work without issue.  I even set the dev tools in IE 10 to IE 8 mode and I do not get the error.

Comment: Interesting. I guess it is a Dojo Mobile issue, then. File an issue there. I do not know Dojo almost at all, but I guess it is open source? If so and you want to move forward without waiting for their answer and diagnosis, get the uncompressed version and try debugging it. Luckily, Internet Explorer 8 has a Developer Tools feature (not great, but, hey, it exists!), so it is possible!